# Let f be a non-constant, continuous function on the closed unit disk and holomorph is its interior, such that $\|f(z)\|=1$ whenever $\|z\|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f be a non-constant, continuous function on the closed unit disk and holomorph is
its interior, such that $\|f(z)\|=1$ whenever $\|z\|=1$  Prove that $f(D(0, 1)) = D(0, 1).$

I am trying to test this, because I need it for a test, but I have not been able to test this and I have come to think it is false

Comment: how do you define $\|f(z)\|$ and $\|z\|$ ? Is it the module ?

Comment: What made you think that the statement is not correct? Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: See: [Schwarz Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma)

Comment: yes it´s module.

Comment: $f$ has finitely many zeroes inside the unit disc (why?) and it has at least one zero (why?), so one can take a finite Blaschke product (read about that if you want to solve this!) $B$ and then $f/B$ is constant of modulus $1$ (why?); hence $f$ is a finite Blaschke product of some degree $m \ge 1$ and those take each value in the disc $m$ times (including multiplicity) (why?)

Comment: There are several approaches, depending on which tools you have at your disposal. For example: $f$ maps the unit disk into itself (Schwarz Lemma).  Then  the boundary behavior $f(\partial \Bbb D) \subset \partial \Bbb D$ implies that the mapping is onto.

Comment: @MartinR That $f$ maps the disk into itself is the Maximum Modulus Principle, not Schwarz Lemma.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: You are right, that is what I actually meant.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2536304/42969.