holomorphic function on unit disc that maps boundary of $\mathbb{D}$ into itself
Let $\mathbb{D} = \{|z| < 1\}$. Let $f : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ be non constant holomorphic map that extends continuously to $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Show that if $f(\partial \mathbb{D}) \subset \partial \mathbb{D}$ then $f(\overline{\mathbb{D}}) = \overline{\mathbb{D}}$.
My attempt:
Since we know that $f(\partial \mathbb{D}) \subset \partial \mathbb{D}$, $|f(z)| = 1$ when $|z| = 1$ so $\sup_{|z| = 1} |f(z)| = 1$. Then the maximum principle tells us that $\sup_{\mathbb{D}} |f| \leq \sup_{|z| = 1} |f(z)|  = 1$. Thus we have that $f(\overline{\mathbb{D}}) \subset \overline{\mathbb{D}}$.
I am not sure how to show the other inclusion $\overline{\mathbb{D}} \subset f(\overline{\mathbb{D}})$.

Also you can refer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536304/show-a-non-constant-continuous-function-f-bard-rightarrow-bard-is-such?noredirect=1

conceptually the answer is implied by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4549376/range-of-an-analytic-function-on-a-unit-disc/ though in this problem we don't know $f$ to be analytic on the boundary-- uniform continuity of $f$ on $\overline {\mathbb D}$ and Dog-on-a-Leash lemma gives a workaround to make invoke the Argument Principle here

In order to complete your proof, we can use the following fact: $f(\mathbb{D}) = f(\bar{\mathbb{D}}) \cap \mathbb{D}$. This equality follows easily from the fact that  $f(\partial \mathbb{D}) \subset \partial\mathbb{D}$ and we can use either the maximum principle or the open mapping theorem to show that $f(\mathbb{D}) \subset \mathbb{D}$.
Using the fact that $f$ is continous and $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ is a compact we obtain
that $f(\bar{\mathbb{D}})$ is compact therefore closed. Combining this fact with the previous equality yields that $f(\mathbb{D})$ is closed in $\mathbb{D}$ with the subspace topology.
Now we use the open mapping theorem to see that $f(\mathbb{D})$ is also open
in $\mathbb{D}$. Thus $f(\mathbb{D})$ is both closed and open in $\mathbb{D}$, therefore we have $f(\mathbb{D}) = \mathbb{D}$. To conclude the proof we use the fact that the continuous extension of $f$ to $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ is closed because $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ is compact, thus we have $f(\bar{\mathbb{D}}) = \bar{\mathbb{D}}$.
